# mount cifs problems on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mount, fstab, cifs

I have a two similar Ubuntu servers 18.04 (4.15.0-39-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 23 15:48:01 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux) and trying to mount windows files server share on it. On one server it's mounting without problem but on second one failing with invalid argument error:

> mount error(22): Invalid argument Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual
>   page (e.g. man mount.cifs)

Executing same command on both servers:

> mount -t cifs -o username=username,domain=domain-name //path/to/share
>   /mount/path

Kernel log write such messages:

> [Tue Dec  4 13:48:36 2018] No dialect specified on mount. Default has
>   changed to a more secure dialect, SMB2.1 or later (e.g. SMB3), from
>   CIFS (SMB1). To use the less secure SMB1 dialect to access old servers
>   which do not support SMB3 (or SMB2.1) specify vers=1.0 on mount. [Tue
>   Dec  4 13:48:36 2018] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -22

Answer (score 5):

The Kernel messeage says it: The default SMB dialect doesn't work and you have to specify it.
The MAN Page of mount.cifs explains the option:

```
   vers=
       SMB protocol version. Allowed values are:
       ·   1.0 - The classic CIFS/SMBv1 protocol. This is the default.
       ·   2.0 - The SMBv2.002 protocol. This was initially introduced in Windows Vista Service Pack 1, and Windows Server 2008. Note that the initial release version of
           Windows Vista spoke a slightly different dialect (2.000) that is not supported.
       ·   2.1 - The SMBv2.1 protocol that was introduced in Microsoft Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008R2.
       ·   3.0 - The SMBv3.0 protocol that was introduced in Microsoft Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012.
       Note too that while this option governs the protocol version used, not all features of each version are available.
```

So you should try to find out which SMB dialect your server is speaking and specify it in your command

Example:

```
mount -t cifs -o username=username,domain=domain-name,vers=1.0 //path/to/share /mount/path
```

Link to the man page for further reference: https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs

Comment: I have tried all protocol version but no one helped... same mount error.